# XCode gles frame capture debugging -- call stack not symbolicated

Tags: xcode, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using Xcode 7.0 , capture gles frame in ipad air ios 8.1.
Debug information format set to "DWARF with dSYM File" and has dSYM file along with .app file.
How can I find the symbols ?

This is the screen shot:
[missing symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghfd3.jpg)

I run the opengl demo project of Xcode and still can't find symbols. Maybe it's a bug of xcode ?